# How to fire event reciever for save button on newform.aspx

Tags: events, sharepoint, eventreceiver

I am working sharepoint 2010 . I am new to this field.i have created event receiver for item added. but it is not firing when i am clcking save button of newform.aspx. I am confused that from where we will call this function. can anyone help me to find out solution for this.

Comment: Event receivers dont trigger on click of a button. On click of a button data is just submitted to server. Once server receives the data and processes it, event receivers are triggered. Please explain what exactly you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can check attributes ListTemplateId / ListUrl int file "Element.xml" is match the target list.

Otherwise you can download [Sharepoint Manager 2010](http://spm.codeplex.com/releases/view/35932) to check event receiver is already added to your list.